# Fatal error when csrf_protection fail

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have enabled `csrf_protection`, and I don't know if it works as expected.

I added (automatically with `form_open`) on HTML forms the field `csrf_test_name`. But if I change the value (or remove it) I get Fatal Error:

> Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /home/user/workspace-php/myprojectsystem/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 366
>
> Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /home/user/workspace-php/myproject/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 366

I think it's supposed to fail on form validation, am I wrong?

**EDIT**

I forgot to say that I am using Modular Extensions - HMVC.

Comment: which version of codeigniter it is?